# Center Logo in the navbar

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble centering my logo in the navbar. I've looked through other posts, but none of the solutions seem to work without messing something else. I don't understand why the logo won't center and I need the site to be responsive.

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-1 order-md-0 dual-collapse2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Recruitment</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="events.html">Events</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="mx-auto order-0">
      <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="template.html">
        <img src = "logo.png" width="100" alt="logo thing">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="hamburger-menu">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Leadership</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sisterhood</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Philanthropy</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here's the css for the html.

```
.navbar>.container .navbar-brand-centered, 
.navbar>.container-fluid .navbar-brand-centered {
    margin-left: -80px;
    position: relative;
    float: center;
    }
}


.navbar{
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 1em;
}

/* change spacing for nav items*/
.navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding-right: 2.5rem;
    padding-left: 2.5rem;
}

.nav-item, .navbar-nav{
  font-family: Montserrat;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a working snippet / fiddle / codepen with the full CSS? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
.navbar>.container .navbar-brand-centered, 
.navbar>.container-fluid .navbar-brand-centered {
    margin-left: -80px;
    position: relative;
    float: center;
    }
}
```

You have an extra breaking bracket after `float:center;`.

There is no such thing as `float:center`;

There are a variety of ways to center things. The easiest is to:

```
.parent-element {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

If the parent is `position: relative`, you can make the target element position absolute and do this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EQGgpM:

```
.parent-element {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  outline: 1px solid #000;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  outline: 1px solid #cc0000;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An `img` element responds to `text-align: center` just fine.

```css
html, body {
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://telecomputingarchitects.com/media/logo.png" alt="logo" height="48">
```